# mcrypt required when installing Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mcrypt

Trying to move to a new server and I'm having so much trouble!
I'm getting an error when trying to install asking for mcrypt extension. I've added extension=mcrypt.so to my php.ini file but I'm still getting this error:

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for laravel/framework v5.0.16 -> satisfiable by     laravel/framework[v5.0.16].
- laravel/framework v5.0.16 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php.ini
    - /etc/php.d/00-ioncube-loader.ini
    - /etc/php.d/curl.ini
    - /etc/php.d/dom.ini
    - /etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php.d/gd.ini
    - /etc/php.d/imap.ini
    - /etc/php.d/json.ini
    - /etc/php.d/mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php.d/mysql.ini
    - /etc/php.d/mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php.d/pdo.ini
    - /etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /etc/php.d/phar.ini
    - /etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini
    - /etc/php.d/wddx.ini
    - /etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php.d/xsl.ini
    - /etc/php.d/zend_extensions_psa.ini
    - /etc/php.d/zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you restart your web server, and have you verified (with `phpinfo()` or `php -i` on the command line) that you edited the right php.ini file?

Comment: have you installed the PHP-Mcrypt package? sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt for ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

you should use php -m to check whether you have installed the mcrypt module.

or you can use function phpinfo() to see if you compile php with config --with-mcrypt

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `ubuntu`, please notice that `php.ini` file path is different between `cli mode` and `fpm mode`.

please make sure which `php.ini` file you are using.